# The ssh-keygen command not making a key on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to create a new ssh key but when running `ssh-keygen -rsa -b 4096` it does not generate the key. It looks like the following:

```
> ssh-keygen -rsa -b 4096
no keys found.
```

My .ssh folder looks like this:

```
.ssh
  |
  - known_hosts (File)
```

And also my computer specifications are:

- Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
- System Model: Inspiron 5370
- System Type: x64-based PC

Does anyone know any fix to this and how I can make a ssh key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made a typing mistake.  If you want to create an RSA key, you need to use `-t rsa`, not `-rsa`.  The `-t` argument specifies the type.  In your case, you've accidentally typed a different command (one equivalent to `-r sa`).

Just as a note, if you don't absolutely need an RSA key, the best practice for SSH keys these days is Ed25519, according to the Mozilla recommendations.  You could create such a key with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` (no `-b` argument needed).

Comment: Worked. Thanks for helping